# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [DELETE] "/logout"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently following Michael Hartl's RoR Tutorial and on Chapter 8: Log In, Log Out > Listing 8.28.

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out

**test/integration/users_login_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:aniket)
  end

  test "login with valid information" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
end
```

As instructed I am performing a test for user logout. I have gone through my code and is exactly as it is mentioned in the book. However, when i run the test suite  i get the following error.

**1) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [DELETE] "/logout"
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:40:in `block in '
21 runs, 53 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips**

I can't seem to understand where i went wrong. Please help

Comment: What are your `routes`? The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. You don't have the `DELETE "/logout"` route. Post the part of your `config/routes.rb` file where you declare that route.

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get 'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  get 'logout'   => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end

Comment: `get 'logout'` is not the same as `delete 'logout'`. Your test expects `delete 'logout'`.

Comment: No, the link you posted clearly says `delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'`.

Comment: My bad. Missed that bit of detail!